# Is it really necessary to create foreign key in this query?

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have a table called investors having a primary key as `ID`. I also have additional tables named Users Login_Logs and Accounts. All of these tables contain the foreign key investor_id. Between investors and Users we have a one to one relation. between investors and Login_Logs a one to many relation and between investors and Acccounts a one to many relation as well. My question is in order to create a query that loads info contained in the table Users, Login_Logs and Accounts - do I need to store the Users id, Accounts id and Login_Logs id in the investors table? I mean, do I need to create foreign keys in the investors table for all columns?

Answer (score 1):

No, foreign key constraints don't affect joins and read queries.  They ensure that the values in the child column(s) exist in the referenced column(s).  They're used for integrity, not for linking rows or tables.

AFAICT recording the user id in your investors table is redundant, and recording the account and login_log ids in investors isn't practical.

To be able to join the tables efficiently, what you need is to index the investor_id in each of the tables.  Then, it's up to your query to connect the tables as required.

The problem with retrieving all the information about investors at the same time is that you have (multiple) one-to-many relations.  If we join all the tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM investors i
JOIN users u ON i.ID = u.investor_id
JOIN accounts a ON i.ID = a.investor_id
JOIN login_logs l ON i.ID = l.investor_id
```

Then, if an investor has 2 accounts and 2 login_logs, then we'll get 4 rows.  SQL databases can't nest related data.  Instead, you may have to use 3 queries to retrieve everything about investors:

```
SELECT *
FROM investors i
JOIN users u ON i.ID = u.investor_id

SELECT *
FROM accounts

SELECT *
FROM login_logs
```

Then process the results in code.  You *could* process the combined query above programmatically, but it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understood your answer but now the point is how to create a query in sequelize that retrieve efficiently all the investors and at the same time all the info that are in the other tables. Do you have any idea?

Comment: My quey should be select all the investors and show all in the info in the other tables related to every investors

Comment: But I don't know how to do this in sequelize without create foreign keys inside investors table. It should exist another way

Comment: Yes this is true that SQL can't nest related data but in sequelize if you can use http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#eager-loading in that way you can neste data and if I place the foreign keys inside investors I could do something like that

Comment: My apologies, I don't know anything about Sequelize nor do I care to learn an ORM.  Perhaps a new question that focuses on the Sequelize query would be in order.